proving that a monotonic function preserves the order of a relation
i'm trying to prove a theorem in a textbook i'm reading.
how can i improve my answer?
thm: $\geq$ is a preference relation on $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$. suppose $u(x)$ is a function that represents $\geq$.
then $v(x)$ also represents $\geq$ if and only if $v(x) = f(u(x))$, where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing on the set of values taken by $u(x)$.
pf: $\rightarrow$) if if $v(x)$ is equivalent to $\geq$, then $v(x) = f(u(x))$
we assume $v$ is equivalent to $\geq$, so $\forall x, y \in S$ where $S$ is the set of all possible values of $v$, $v(x) \geq v(y)$ or $v(y) \geq v(x)$, but not both.
we also know $f$ is strictly monotonic, so $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$, $f(x) \geq f(y)$ if $x \geq y$.
now let $U$ represent all possible values of $u(x)$. then $\forall x, y \in U$, $f(x) \geq f(y)$ or $f(y) \geq f(x)$, but not both.
this implies that the sets of all possible values of $v$ and $f(u)$ have the same ordering, so $v = f(u)$.
$\leftarrow$) if $v(x) = f(u(x))$, then $v(x)$ is equivalent to $\geq$
we assume $v(x) = f(u(x))$, and we know $u(x)$ is equivalent to $\geq$.
let $S$ be the set of all possible values of $u(x)$, so $\forall x, y \in S$, $x \geq y$ or $y \geq x$, but not both.
$f$ is strictly monotonic, so $f(x) \geq f(y)$ when $x \geq y$.
this implies that the set of all possible values of $v$, $S'$, has the same ordering as $S$, so $v$ is equivalent to $\geq$. $\square$

What is a preference relation? What does it mean that a function represents a preference relation?

@Taroccoesbrocco my understanding is that 1) a preference relation is a subset of Rn+ x Rn+  that is complete and transitive and 2) when a function represents a preference relation, this means that for all values x and y in the domain of f, f(x) >= f(y) implies x >= y and vice versa. have i misunderstood these definitions in my proof or in this comment or both?

Is a preference relation in your context reflexive or not?  In your proof it seems to be irreflexive, but $\geq$ is usually used for reflexive relations.

If in your context a preference relation is irreflexive, then it is a bit confusing that you are using $\geq$ to mean a complete relation that is not reflexive (so for all x we have $x\not\geq x$).
If it is instead reflexive, then it is perfectly possible that both $x \geq y$ and $ y \geq x$, in particular when $y=x$. If you don't want this, then you have to specify that it is for distinct $x$ and $y$.
There are some problems with the fact that you evaluate $f$ in $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$. It is also not clear if $S$ should be all of $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$ or not.
I'll try to give a more polished version for the reflexive case:
thm: Consider a binary relation $\geq$ that is a preference relation (total transitive relation) on $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$. Suppose that $u\colon \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function that represents $\geq$.
Then $v\colon \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ also represents $\geq$ if and only if $v = f \circ u$ for some function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is strictly increasing on the set of values taken by $u$.
pf: Let $>$ be the strict version of $\geq$.
$\Rightarrow$) If $v$ represents $\geq$, then $v = f \circ u$ for some strictly increasing $f$.
We assume $v$ represents $\geq$.
So, $\forall x, y \in S$, where $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$ is the domain on which $v$ is defined, $v(x) > v(y)$ or $v(y) > v(x)$, but not both.
Now let $U=\{u(x)| x\in S \}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ represent all possible values of $u$ and let $f\colon U \to \{v(x)|x\in S\}$ be defined by $f(u(x))=v(x)$ for all (x\in S).
Since both $u$ and $v$ represent $\geq$ we have that $f(u(x))=v(x) > v(y)=f(u(y))$ if and only if $u(x) > u(y)$ for all $x,y \in S$.
Therefore, $f$ is strictly increasing.
$\Leftarrow$) If $v = f \circ u$ for some strictly increasing $f$, then $v$ represents $\geq$.
We assume $v(x) = f(u(x))$ for all $x\in S$, and we know $u$ represents $\geq$.
Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be the set of all possible values of $u(x)$, so $\forall r, s \in U$, $r > s$ or $s > r$, but not both.
$f$ is strictly monotone, so $f(r) > f(s)$ when $r > s$.
Since the real numbers are totally ordered, this implies that the set $V$ of all possible values of $v$, has the same ordering as $U$, so $v$ is equivalent to $\geq$. $\square$
